# Best sorting algorithm for sorting structs with byte comparisons?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct

I have an array of 64 structs that hold a decent amount of data (struct is around 128 bytes, so that's 8192 bytes that need to be re-arragned). The array needs to be sorted based off a single unsigned byte in each struct. An interesting property of my data is that it is likely that there will be many duplicates of sorted value - meaning that if you got rid of all duplicates, the array may only be 10 unique elements long, but this is not a given.

Once sorted, I need to create a stack that stores the size and type that each unique byte-run starts:
so if I ended up with sorted values:
4,4,4,9,9,9,9,9,14,14
the stack would be:
(4,3), (9,5), (14,2)

I figured that there would be some nice optimizations I could perform under these conditions. If I do heapsort, I can create the stack while I'm sorting, but would this be faster than a qsort and then build the stack afterwords? Would any sorting algorithm run slower because of the large structs I'm using? Any optimizations I can make because I'm only comparing bytes?

BTW: language is c++

Thanks.

Comment: What would you use for a stack, something homemade or built-in?

Comment: I want the fastest, so I imagine it will a simple homemade one that uses a fixed buffer.

Comment: Do you need to actually sort or do you just need the "stack" that stores the size and type?

Comment: I need them sorted, but an unstable sort would work too.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine that STL will do what you want nicely.  Re-writing your own sort routines and containers is likely to be error-prone, and slow.  So only worry about if you find it's a bottleneck.

Comment: I'm against the use of std for this purpose, as I can't be sure of the way it sorts! I want to use the most efficient implementation, not a generic one. Thanks, though.

Comment: @Pepe: You haven't even measured them, but you're against it based on a hunch?  STL routines are generally very, very good.  Like I said, if you haven't even measured it, then you shouldn't be worrying about it.

Comment: Well, I need the fastest, and in order to test STL against my own, I would have to write my own. I will take your advice and test STL when I get mine done.

Comment: @Pepe: Note also that with only 64 elements to sort, there's going to be precious little difference between different algorithms anyway.

Comment: @Pepe: No, you don't need the fastest!  You need the one that's fast enough so that this part of your code is no longer the bottleneck.  What you are attempting is called premature optimization.

Comment: I am perfectionist and I know that this function needs to run optimal, as a large portion of my rendering engine runs off of it. I don't think this is an appropriate place to discuss whether or not the optimization is needed, as all I need to know the fastest algorithm, not whether or not I should do it.

Comment: @Pepe: If you want to waste your time, and end up with brittle, hard-to-read, hand-written containers and sort routines, etc., then be my guest!  But this is not a good approach to developing performance-critical code.

Comment: If I wanted nice generic code that prefers looks over speed then I would be using a different language. I would not be posting here if this did not have to run extremely fast and optimized!

Comment: @Pepe: You've done nothing to convince me that you know that you *need* to optimise this bit of code (don't worry, I don't need to be convinced!).  It sounds like you just *want* to.  Optimising at the expense of code readability and potential bugginess *before* you've proved it's an issue is pointless, at best.  For all you know, this is only taking 5% of your total runtime anyway, so you'll gain a 1.05x speedup even if you optimise it away to nothing!  Please read about Amdahl's Law.

Comment: I didn't come here to argue about this! I know I need to implement a sorting algorithm, and so I want to know best one for the job. Whether or not I optimize this algorithm to 1.05% speedup, I know I can gain big boost with correct algorithm.

Comment: @Pepe: That's fine by me.  But seriously, this is probably the best answer you're going to get, even if it's not what you want to hear.

Comment: I will test out 3 methods and benchmark them. If you are interested in results I can give them to you. Anyways, interesting side note is that I optimize the function that genererated the data to be sorted, and ended up with 5000% speed boost after switching from std implementation to a very custom one. This is why I am skeptical of use of STD in parts of code that need to run fast.

Comment: @Pepe: I would be interested, yes.  Add them to your question when you have them.

Comment: Alright. It may be a few days as I haven't gotten to the part where I need to implement this though.

Comment: @Pepe If you don't already know how to do this then you won't beat std.

Comment: What? I know how to write sorting algorithms, I just don't want to write 3 to figure out the fastest.

Comment: @Pepe if you really knew then why are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

In general with large objects it can be faster to sort an array of pointers/indices of the objects rather than the objects. Or sort an array of nodes, where each node contains a pointer/index of the object and the object's sort key (in this case the key is one byte). To do this in C++ you can just supply a suitable comparator to `std::sort` or `std::stable_sort`. Then if you need the original objects in order, as opposed to just needing to know the correct order, finally copy the objects into a new array.

Copying 128 bytes is almost certainly much slower than performing a byte comparison, even with an extra indirection. So for optimal performance it's the moves you need to look at, not the comparisons, and dealing in pointers is one way to avoid most of the moving.

You could build your run-length encoding as you perform the copy at the end.

Of course it might be possible to go even faster with some custom sorting algorithm which makes special use of the numbers in your case (64, "around 128", and 1). But even simple questions like "which is fastest - introsort, heap sort or merge sort" are generally impossible to answer without writing and running the code.

Comment: Yeah, I was planning on using a byte to store the indices. I am correct when I say that I need a double buffer?

Comment: You don't strictly need one: you need to re-arrange an array according to an arbitrary permutation, which can be done in-place by identifying the cycles of the permutation and re-arranging each cycle in turn, using only a single object's worth of additional space. Also: no guarantees, but my guess is that it would be faster to use a word to store the index and another for the sort key, rather than a byte each. So try both and see which you prefer.

Comment: Ok, I will experiment. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The sort would not be slower because you will be sorting pointer or references to the structs and not the actual struct in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your keys are integers, and there really aren't a lot of them,
odds are the [Bucket Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort), with a bucket size of 1, would be very applicable.

Comment: The only problem with this is that I believe I would have to allocate 16384 bytes for buckets, and also need to use a double buffer for the actual data. Is this correct? Would this be faster than a heapsort?

Comment: You could just add the buckets as you go along, by using a map of vectors of pointers to your data.

Comment: I have feeling that all the allocation in the vectors would slow that down.

Comment: declare the array static, and make it integer.   It will run like lightening.